# Having trouble in fetching existing api (anilist api) via apollo-angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, graphql, apollo-angular

I am trying to fetch data from anilist api (https://github.com/AniList/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs) via [apollo-angular](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/).
Connection seems to be developed but not able to get data on client side. I need help. If someone know how to solve it. Code is here (https://gofile.io/d/deMTTY) and node_module file excluded just run traditional npm install to install dependencies.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try to give us some reproducible example based on stackblitz or similar to try to debug your problem.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pl6xhr